# Команда 'Команда' не найдена

Tags: discord.py, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="%", help_command=None, intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот готов к работе")

    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Помощь - %help")) # Изменяем статус боту


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):  
    await bot.process_commands(message) 

    msg = message.content.lower()
    greeting_words = ["hello", "hi", "привет"]             #вариации приветов
    censored_words = ["дурак", "дура", "придурок","говно"] #запрещенные слова

    if msg in greeting_words:
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, приветствую тебя!")

    # Фильтр запрещенных слов
    for bad_content in msg.split(" "):
        if bad_content in censored_words:
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, Полегче, не на базаре же...")


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    """Работа с ошибками
    """
    print(error)

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author}, у вас недостаточно прав для выполнения данной команды!")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.UserInputError):
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            description=f"Правильное использование команды: `{ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.name}` ({ctx.command.brief})\nExample: {ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.usage}"
        ))


@bot.command(name="очистить", brief="Очистить чат от сообщений, по умолчанию 10 сообщений", usage="clear <amount=10>")
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=10):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(f"Удалены {amount} сообщений...")


@bot.command(name="кик", brief="Выгнать пользователя с сервера", usage="kick <@user> <reason=None>")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete(delay=1) # Если желаете удалять сообщение после отправки с задержкой



@bot.command(name="бан", brief="Забанить пользователя на сервере", usage="ban <@user> <reason=None>")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.send(f"You was banned on server") # Отправить личное сообщение пользователю
    await ctx.send(f"Member {member.mention} was banned on this server")
    await member.ban(reason=reason)


@bot.command(name="разбанить", brief="Разбанить пользователя на сервере", usage="unban <user_id>")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, user_id: int):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
    await ctx.guild.unban(user)


@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    """Команда help
    Чтобы не писать тысячу строк одинакового кода, лучше занесем название и описание команд в списки,
    и переберм в цикле.
    """

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Команды для использования бота:",
        description="Доступные команды:"
    )
    commands_list = ["clear", "kick", "ban", "unban"]
    descriptions_for_commands = ["Очистить чатик", "Выгнать пользователя", "Забанить пользователя", "Разбанить пользователя"]

    for command_name, description_command in zip(commands_list, descriptions_for_commands):
        embed.add_field(
            name=command_name,
            value=description_command,
            inline=False # Будет выводиться в столбик, если True - в строчку
        )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@bot.command(name="мут", brief="Запретить пользователю писать (настройте роль и канал)", usage="mute <member>")
async def mute_user(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="role name")

    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author} gave role mute to {member}")

    """Временный мут
    Также вы можете сделать временный мут, для этого используйте модуль asyncio и метод sleep (asyncio.sleep).
    Пусть функция принимает параметр time_mute. Поставьте условие if "h" in time_mute:
    То есть, если вы пишите: !mute @user 1h, и в переменной time_mute находит букву "h" значит asyncio.sleep(time_mute[:1] * 3600)
    
    """


@bot.command(name="join", brief="Подключение к голосовому каналу", usage="join")
async def join_to_channel(ctx):
    global voice
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Bot was connected to the voice channel")


@bot.command(name="leave", brief="Отключение от голосового канала", usage="leave")
async def leave_from_channel(ctx):
    global voice
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        voice = await channel.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f"Bot was connected to the voice channel")


bot.run("TOKEN")

  [![Ошибка при любой команды][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5X3w.png
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)